# PHP file works in cloud server but not on localhost

Tags: php, html, localhost

I am creating a chat room using PHP, and it works completely fine on my cloud servers but not on local host, any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

        </style>
        </head>
<body>
<form action="chatroom.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="input">
<input type="submit">
 </form>

 <br>

<?php
$file = fopen("database.txt","r+");
$data = fread($file,filesize("database.txt"));
fclose($file);
if($_REQUEST["input"]=="adminclear"){
$data = "";
}
file_put_contents('database.txt',"<div>". $data . $_REQUEST["name"].":".$_REQUEST["input"]. "<br> </div>");
echo $data;
?> 
<script>

        </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: @AbraCadaver if I could put this as helpful more than once i would.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Are the permission right?

Comment: No errors, just the text document isn't changing.

Comment: That's why you add the code so that errors will display.  Also, while developing, change those settings in `php.ini` so you will always see all errors.

Comment: How? Sorry, I'm completely knew to this.

Comment: Are you running your entire (shown) code in one big lump? If so, then split them up, or set action to `<form action="" method="post">` also check for file permissions on `database.txt`

Comment: How do I change to file permission on database.txt?

Comment: `chmod 644 database.txt` in your FTP program. Or use `777` but that's not the safest setting.

Comment: You can also put this `chmod("database.txt", 0644);` underneath `$file = fopen("database.txt","r+");` or `chmod("database.txt", 0777);` depending on which setting works.

Comment: The permission worked! Thanks alot!

Comment: You're welcome. I will put in an answer to close the question properly. @user2707299

Comment: check for the database.txt file permission and make use of $_POST instead of $_REQUEST

Comment: To close the question properly and mark as answered, click the white checkmark till it turns green next to my answer. Otherwise, it will remain in the unanswered category. @user2707299

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for file permissions on `database.txt`

`chmod 644 database.txt` in your FTP program. Or use `777` but that's not the safest setting.

You can also put this `chmod("database.txt", 0644);`

underneath `$file = fopen("database.txt","r+");` or `chmod("database.txt", 0777);` depending on which setting works best for you.